# .Net compiler resolve package dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection, dependency-management

I am writing an app in .NET 6.0. It allows the end user to load an arbitrary assembly using Assembly.LoadFrom. Then it uses reflection to call its methods. THAT IS ALL.
The challenge is: I have no way to predict what assembly the user is going to load and what dependencies that assembly has. The possibilities are infinite.

I have a project which contains a simple user interface project and a simple "DataAccess" class library project which reads employees and teams from a SQL Server database. This DataAccess.dll is used to test my code. The DataAccess.csproj file contains a package reference PackageReference Include=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="7.0.16".

When my code tried to invoke methods in the DataAccess.dll using reflection, the ResolveAssembly event was fired many times, asking me to load all the dependencies. When one of the events was fired, the ResolveEventArgs.Name was "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=23ec7fc2d6eaa4a5". It is one of the dependencies of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.

However, when my code in the ResolveAssembly event handler searches for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll under the C:\Users[username].nuget\packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient folder, there isn't a 5.0.0.0 subfolder. Instead, there are three folders 5.0.1, 5.0.2 and 5.1.4.

Which one shall I choose? THIS IS THE PROBLEM THAT I NEED YOUR HELP.

The "DataAccess.deps.json" file contains the answer:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/5.1.4:

```
"dependencies": [
...
],
"runtime": [
"lib/net6.0/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll": [
"assemblyVersion": "5.0.0.0",
"fileVersion": "5.14.24005.1"
]
]
```

"5.1.4" is actually the package version, while "5.0.0.0" is the assemblyVersion. But I can't use this file because not all .NET core projects have a deps.json file. Since the end users may use my app to load any arbitrary assembly, I can't make this assumption.

Could someone tell me how I can solve this?

Comment: If someone loads a dll you should use something like Nuget package manager to restore dependencies and only then you would be sure that you have all dependencies of that dll.

Comment: /1 Hey, I remember this request on Upwork!)) Trying to make a buck by posting your client's project description here and getting free help, huh? Smart))) I will tell you same that I told your client: it is not possible to build a universal loader and predict what NuGet package has to be loaded for all 100% cases. Moreover your choice will be different for different environments and point in time. All you can do is an educated guess that will work for most of the popular NuGet packages from reliable vendors that follow guidelines. Private NuGet repos most probably will be a horror.

Comment: /2 There is a good reason why plugins are shipped together with all the dependencies and not as a single DLL: you don't have enough information to load those dependencies automatically (unless somebody embeds required information using custom assembly attributes)

Comment: /3 Regarding your question about correct Microsoft.Data.SqlClient version: depends on your strategy. If we are talking particularly about this case, I would load 5.1.4 because guidelines say that next minor versions should be backwards compatible and .NET team tries to follow these recommendations. In case of other less responsible authors you never know if they kept backwards compatibility, so you either have to load *probably* most compatible version (in this case 5.0.0) or its bug fix (5.0.2). Either way it is still a risk because a developer could have used v5.1.4