# Get package resolution hints from NuGet using its client SDK

Tags: reflection, nuget, .net-6.0

I am writing a **.NET 6.0** console app that uses reflection to

1. Load an **arbitrary** class library (DLL) - I can't predict what DLL the end user may load - the possibilities are infinite.
2. Find out its public types and the methods of each type
3. Invoke its methods.

For the loaded assembly to work, my app needs to load the **dependency graph** - all of its dependencies and the dependencies of each dependency and so on recursively. For each of the dependency which is itself a DLL, if it is not in the global NuGet packages folder, my app downloads it from NuGet online library and unzips it into the global folder.

Is this the right approach? Or is there a fundamentally better approach?

A problem I encountered is how to pick the right DLL in the NuGet package folder.

In my testing, the target DLL which my console app tried to load and invoke uses **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.16** to talk to a SQL Server database. It has a dependency **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.4**. Inside the NuGet package folder of **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.1.4**, there are the following subfolders that each contains a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll:

1. lib\net6.0
2. lib\net462
3. lib\netstandard2.0
4. lib\netstandard2.1
5. runtimes\win\lib\net6.0
6. runtimes\win\lib\net462
7. runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0
8. runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.1

You would think that the one in "**lib\net6.0**" has to be the right one, because my console app targets .NET 6.0, wouldn't you? But if my console app loads this one, it would case a exception saying this DLL is not supported. However, if I use the one in "**runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0**", everything works.

So the question is: where is the knowledge that I should use the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll in folder "**runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0**" instead of "**lib\net6.0**" for **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.16**?

The following is how to get dependencies of a given DLL. It doesn't contain the knowledge I am after:

```
        NuspecReader nuspecReader = await packageReader.GetNuspecReaderAsync(cancellationToken);

        foreach (var dependencyGroup in nuspecReader.GetDependencyGroups())
        {
                foreach (NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackageDependency packageDependency in dependencyGroup.Packages)
                {
                    ...
                }
        }
```

However, Visual Studio secretly knows where to get this knowledge, because if I add a reference to **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 7.0.16** in any .Net 6.0 project, Visual Studio will automatically pick the right Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll in the global NuGet packages folder.

But where is this knowledge, so my console app can use to load the right DLL?

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78106610/net-compiler-resolve-package-dependencies